# How to stash different between two branches?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea, terminal, git-branch

I have two branches **branch_1** and **branch_2** on my local IDE. I want to stash changes between **branch_1** and **branch_2** . How can I do it ? Please Help me with git commands.
**What actually I want is to create a new branch   ***branch_new***   and in that new branch I want to have changes of **branch_1** and **branch_2** .**
So , I think I need to first get stash somehow and then pop that stash on my **branch_new** .
Suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Can you explain why you want to do that? AFAIK the `git stash` only allows to stash some uncommited changes.

Comment: I know what git stash does , What I want is to have changes of two branch and apply that changes on some other branch.

Comment: You should update your question with this detail so that we can understand your actual need :)

Comment: Why not create the new branch and merge your 1st branch into it, then the 2nd?

Answer (score 2):

Based on comment

> What I want is to have changes of two branch and apply that changes on
> some other branch.

`cherry-pick` is an ideal way if the commits are pushed into **branch_1** and **branch_2** already.

1. make sure you switched to the correct branch where you want to apply changes, i.e. **branch_new**

   `git switch branch_new`
2. Execute cherry-pick command as following

   `git cherry-pick <commit-hash>`

get `commit-hash` value of each commit that you want in new branch, by browsing through `git log`

**Note**:

use `git cherry-pick -x <commit-hash>` if you get commits from public repository. This will help to generate commit message and track origin of the commit change. hence you can refer in future to avoid merge conflicts.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using IntelliJ, apart from stash, there is a feature called "Shelve". Whatever the changes that moved to shelves when you right click on default change list of changed files(yet to be committed) and select shelve changes. Later after changed to a different branch as per your choice, unshelve the change and that will be now in default changes. You can commit that to new branch.

Answer (score 1):

You can stash the changes on `branch_1` using `git stash` while on branch_1.

Now, create a new branch and switch to it.

Apply the stash created using `git stash pop` on the new branch.

You can do same with the `branch_2` as well

Answer (score 1):

You can apply changes to another branch via UI as well.
It can be achieved with features available in IDE:

1. [Cherry-pick](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#5fb49315)
2. [Cherry-Pick Selected Changes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/apply-changes-from-one-branch-to-another.html#apply-separate-changes)